# Repeating Record Sequence using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

This could easily be done using code, but I wondered if it could be done at the database level using SQL Server (2008).

I have a table similar to below:

```
CROP_ID   YEAR_   PRODUCTION   
1         1       0  
1         2       300  
1         3       500  
2         1       100
2         2       700
```

I want to be able to run a query to repeat this for *n* number of years, per crop type e.g.

```
CROP_ID  YEAR_  PRODUCTION  
1        1      0  
1        2      300  
1        3      500  
1        4      0  
1        5      300
1        6      500
etc.
```

I'm not sure of the best approach, I presume I would need a SP and pass in a year variable, and use a loop construct? However the exact syntax escapes me. Any help appreciated.

**Update**

Sorry for not providing all the information in my original post. The table will allow for multiple crop types, and for Produciton values to be updated so Case statements with fixed variables are not really suitable. Apologies for not being clearer.

**Update**

With the TVF answer I used the following modified SQL to select by CropType for 20 years.

```
select top 20 b.CROP_ID,  
YEAR_ = n.num * (select count() from MyBaseTable where CROP_ID = 3) + b.YEAR,  
b.PRODUCTION from MyBaseTable b, dbo.fnMakeNRows(20) n  
where CROP_ID = 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a table-valued-function instead of a stored proc, which gives a little more flexibility for what you do with the result (as it can be selected from directly, inserted into another table, joined to other tables, etc).

You could also make this more generic by having a TVF generate N rows (with a number from 0 to N-1 on each row) and then use some simple expressions to generate the columns you need from this. I have found such a TVF to be useful in a variety of situations.

If you need to generate more complicated data than you can with 0..N-1 and simple expressions, then you should create a TVF dedicated to your specific needs.

The following example shows how a generic TVF could be used to generate the data you ask for:

```
create function fnMakeNRows (@num as integer)
returns @result table (num integer not null) as
begin
 if @num is null or @num = 0
 begin
  return
 end
 declare @n as integer
 set @n = 0
 while @n < @num
 begin
  insert into @result values (@n)
  set @n = @n + 1
 end
 return
end
go

select
 CROP_ID = 1,
 YEAR_ = num,
 PRODUCTION = case num % 3 when 0 then 0 when 1 then 300 else 500 end
from dbo.fnMakeNRows(100000)
```

You can also use this to duplicate rows in an existing table (which I think is more like what you want). For example, assuming base_table contains the three rows at the beginning of your question, you can turn the 3 rows into 60 rows using the following:

```
select
 b.CROP_ID,
 YEAR_ = n.num * (select count(*) from base_table) + b.YEAR_,
 b.PRODUCTION
from base_table b, dbo.fnMakeNRows(20) n
```

This (hopefully) shows the utility of a generic fnMakeNRows function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've not used TVFs before so it was good to try out. The second Select statement brought back exactly the results I need. Now I'm just stuck choosing which approach to take!

Comment: Adding a second crop type to the table messes up the Years, so I modified the statement. The TOP keyword defines the number of years, as a YEAR_ < does not seem to work:

select top 20  
 b.CROP_ID,  
 YEAR_ = n.num * (select count(*) from MyBaseTable where CROP_ID = 3) + b.YEAR_,  
 b.PRODUCTION  
from MyBaseTable b, dbo.fnMakeNRows(20) n  
where CROP_ID  = 3

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in standard SQL without creating a stored procedure or using temp tables. The example below will do this for 12 years. You can extend it out to any number of years:

```
insert into CropYield
(CropID, Year_, Production)
Select 1, a.a + (10 * b.a), 
    case (a.a + (10 * b.a)) % 3
        when 0 then 500
        when 1 then 0
        when 2 then 300
    end
from (Select 0 as a union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) as a
cross join (Select 0 as a union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) as b
where a.a + (10 * b.a) between 1 and 12
```

Comment: Nice! Though I'd probably keep a table of integers so I could avoid the unions.

Comment: Depends how you are using it, indexing is probably more of a concern than the UNION. I can generate 1,000,000 rows in under a second on my 4 year-old desktop. For a one-time data load like I think this question is, creating another table is probably unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this is not going to be a static one off query so the case statement and modular approach won't work if values are updated in the table.

Answer (score 1):

A common trick to produce this kind of data without the need of a stored procedure is with the use of ***a table of constants***.  Because such a table can be of generic use, it can be created with say all the integers between 1 and 100 or even 1 and 1,000 depending on usage.

For exmaple

```
CREATE TABLE tblConstNums
( I INT )
INSERT INTO tblConstNums VALUES (1) 
INSERT INTO tblConstNums VALUES (2) 
INSERT INTO tblConstNums VALUES (3) 
INSERT INTO tblConstNums VALUES (4) 
INSERT INTO tblConstNums VALUES (5)
-- ...
INSERT INTO tblConstNums VALUES (1000)
```

The the solution can be written declaratively (without requiring Stored Procedure or more generally procedural statements:

```
SELECT CROP_ID,  YEAR_ * I,   PRODUCTION 
FROM myCropTable T
JOIN tblConstNums C on 1=1
WHERE I in (1, 2, 3)
order by CROP_ID,  YEAR_ * I,   PRODUCTION
```

Note that the table of constants may include several columns for commonly used cases.  For example, and even though many of these can be expressed as mathematical expressions of numbers in a basic 0 to n sequence, one can have a column with only even number, another one with odd numbers, another one with multiples of 5 etc.   Also if it small enough, no indexes are needed on a table of constants but these may become useful on a bigger on.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. However I get two records for each year from year 2 onwards?

Answer (score 1):

use this one:

```
WITH tn (n) as
(
    SELECT 0
  UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1
    FROM tn
  WHERE tn.n < 10
)
SELECT DISTINCT t.CROP_ID, t.YEAR_ + (3*tn.n), t.PRODUCTION
FROM table t, tn 

/*    
    WHERE tn.n < 10 ==> you will get 1 -> (10*3) + 3 = 33

*/
```

Comment: Hi,
I changed the "FROM table" to my table name - is this correct?
Then after running I get a "Recursive member of a common table expression 't' has multiple recursive references" error when running the query. 
This is using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: yes, it's correct to put your table name instead of 'table'.
The error you got was expected and I didn't pay attention to that as I'm doing this mentally, I don't have a server to test. I think now it's ok. Can you test. I've put also another query in case.

Comment: Hi,
Writing recursive SQL statements without a computer? I'm impressed. 
I tried the query again, and the results seem to flash up briefly then I get the following message:
"The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 2 has been exhausted before statement completion."

Comment: Hi - yes that did work =)
I wasn't able to filter by crop type, and have the TVF query working now. Thanks for you help though, and an introduction to recursive SQL.